# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, noclassdeffounderror, illegalstateexception

I am using eclipse luna which is an out-of-date version. I'm having an issue with setting up selenium.I'm using vanilla java, no marven or anything like that.

```
public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException{ 
    

             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Program Files//chromedriver//chromedriver.exe");

             WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


             driver.get("www.google.com"); 
        }
```

I imported JAR files instead of copying in selenium stand-alone. also tried switching the setproperty and driver but it return: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the chromedriver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Comment: these are all the jar i added. i am not using marven so i tried to find a stand-alone jar, idk if they work well. i have managed to use selenium on marven by copying in dependencies but I cant do that here or I don't know how,, the list :   slf4j-api-161 jar

slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar

selenium-api-47.2-jar

org.apache.commons.io.jar

java-json,jar

selenium-java.jar -

selenium-serverZ24.1jar -

selenium-server-standalone-2'7.0

selenium-java-3.140.jar

guava-23.0jar

Comment: this is an apectJ file